# Using os.walk in Python to create a txt file for a corresponding folder and subfolders

Tags: python, os.walk

I have been trying to create a function a that uses os.walk to go through a directory tree and create a text file that is named after the folder and only create it the text file if there is data files in a source folder and append the files to that txt file. It practically makes a backup of the data files on another mapped network drive

```
def copy_from_dest(src, dest):
    os.chdir(src)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".",topdown=True):
        for name in dirs:
            newdir = (os.path.join(root, name))
            os.chdir(newdir)        
            filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')
            if len(filenames) > 1:
                for fname in filenames:
                    add_to_file(src + newdir, fname, dest + newdir, newdir + "_data.txt")
            os.chdir(src)
```

`add_to_file` is a function that appends the files to the text file and removes the afterwards. The problem I am facing is that the first branch of directories works perfectly the second branch (or subdirectory of subdirectory) makes the file in the second branch or second step in when it was suppose to make it in the third.

For example:

- `Root/` folder works fine
- `Root/folderstep1` works fine
- `Root/folderstep1/folderstep2/folderstep3` incorrectly writes the txt file in folderstep2

Please can anyone assist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth parameter to your `add_to_file` function looks suspicious: It seems that you want to construct a file name like `"folderstep3_data.txt"` for the current directory, but instead you're passing something like `./folderstep1/folderstep2/folderstep3_data.txt`. But since I don't know, how `add_to_file` works internally, I cannot tell.

Try logging the parameters to `add_to_file`:

```
print (src + newdir), fname, (dest + newdir), newdir + "_data.txt"
```

and see, if that reveals the problem.

Two additional points:

`if len(filenames)>1:` should probably be a `>0`? Or do you only want to write something, if at least *two* text files exist?

Also, since `os.walk()` already walks all the subdirectories for you and also gives you a list of filenames for every one, couldn't you simply thst, if `files` (the var you get from the `os.walk()`-loop) contains a text file (using `str.endswith('.txt')` and use only `root` as directory?

If you have a structure like

```
+ src
+--+ subfolder 1
|  +-- file1.txt
|  +-- file2.txt
|  +--+ subfolder1.2
|     +-- file3.txt
+--+ subfolder 2
   +-- file4.txt
```

then `os.walk()` will give you

```
root=src, dirs=['subfolder1','subfolder2'], files=[]
root=src\subfolder1, dirs=['subfolder1.2'], files=['file1.txt','file2.txt']
root=src\subfolder1\subfolder1.2, dirs=[], files=['file3.txt']
root=src\subfolder2, files=['file3.txt']
```

So it seems, that `root` and `files` should be enough information to make the call to `add_file`. So there would be no need for `os.chdir()` and `glob.glob()`.

Comment: this is what the add_to_file looks like   `def add_to_file(src, srcfile, dest, destfile):  
    shutil.copy2(src + "\\" + srcfile, dest)  
    os.chdir(dest)  
    with open(destfile, 'a') as outfile:  
        with open(srcfile, 'r') as readfile:  
            infile = readfile.read()  
            for line in infile:  
                outfile.write(line)  
            outfile.write("\n")  
    os.remove(srcfile)  
    os.chdir(src)`

Comment: Even more `chdir`s ... As I said: `os.walk('.')` will give you paths starting with `./` in root. So all directories will be relative ones, and you're constantly changing the current directory. Again: try to `print` the arguments to `add_to_file` (or even inside `add_to_file`), to see, what directories are used for each step. Also, you could use `os.path.abspath()`to make your paths absolute (e.g. just after the first `for`loop, do a `root=os.path.abspath(root)`

Comment: thanks so much. It was the first statement you made. The fourth parameter to the add_to_file function was the issue. I have now resolved and refined it. Thanks again.